# Protocol mismatch. C, sockets, sendall / recvall

Tags: c, sockets, ssh

I simply want to write an application, which connects to my SSH server, sends a message, and receives a response. I do not want to log in, or anything like that, just send the message and get the response. I have a `openSSH` server listening on `192.168.0.1` on port `22`.

However, my code (of course sends and gets the message), prints:

```
SSH-1.99-OpenSSH_4.4
Protocol mismatch.
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int sendAll(int socket, char *buffer, int numBytes)
{
    int ret;           // Return value for 'send'
    int sentBytes;     // Total number of bytes sent

    // Send the given number of bytes.
    sentBytes = 0;

    while (sentBytes < numBytes)
    {
        ret = send(socket, buffer + sentBytes, numBytes - sentBytes, 0);

        // Error encountered.
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            close(socket);
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }
        // Data sent.
        else
        {
            sentBytes += ret;
        }
    }
    return sentBytes;
}

int recvAll(int socket, char *buffer, int numBytes)
{
    int ret;               // Return value for 'recv'
    int receivedBytes;     // Total number of bytes received

    // Retrieve the given number of bytes.
    receivedBytes = 0;
    while ((receivedBytes < numBytes) && ret != -1)
    {
        ret = recv(socket, buffer + receivedBytes, numBytes - receivedBytes, 0);

        // Error encountered.
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            close(socket);
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(ret == 0)
        {
            receivedBytes += ret;
            break;
        }
        // Data received.
        else
        {
            receivedBytes += ret;
        }
    }


    buffer[receivedBytes] = '\0';
    return receivedBytes;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char * ip_addr = "192.168.0.1";
    int port = 22;

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_aton(ip_addr, &server_addr.sin_addr);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("connect");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
    }

    char msg[] = "abc\n";
    char buffer[255];
    int recv_size, send_size;

    send_size = sendAll(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
    recv_size = recvAll(sockfd, buffer, 254);

    buffer[recv_size] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, when I replace `recvall` with `recv`, it shows only: `SSH-1.99-OpenSSH_4.4` like it should. But why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int sendAll(int socket, char *buffer, int numBytes)
{
    int ret;           // Return value for 'send'
    int sentBytes;     // Total number of bytes sent

    // Send the given number of bytes.
    sentBytes = 0;

    while (sentBytes < numBytes)
    {
        ret = send(socket, buffer + sentBytes, numBytes - sentBytes, 0);

        // Error encountered.
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            close(socket);
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }
        // Data sent.
        else
        {
            sentBytes += ret;
        }
    }
    return sentBytes;
}

int recvAll(int socket, char *buffer, int numBytes)
{
    int ret;               // Return value for 'recv'
    int receivedBytes;     // Total number of bytes received

    // Retrieve the given number of bytes.
    receivedBytes = 0;
    while ((receivedBytes < numBytes) && ret != -1)
    {
        ret = recv(socket, buffer + receivedBytes, numBytes - receivedBytes, 0);

        // Error encountered.
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            close(socket);
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(ret == 0)
        {
            receivedBytes += ret;
            break;
        }
        // Data received.
        else
        {
            receivedBytes += ret;
        }
    }


    buffer[receivedBytes] = '\0';
    return receivedBytes;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char * ip_addr = "192.168.0.1";
    int port = 22;

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_aton(ip_addr, &server_addr.sin_addr);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("connect");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
    }

    char msg[] = "abc\n";
    char buffer[255];
    int recv_size, send_size;

    send_size = sendAll(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));

    if ((recv_size = recv(sockfd, buffer, 254, 0)) == 0)
    {
        close(sockfd);
        if (errno != 0)
        {
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    buffer[recv_size] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `recv` need not receive *everything* in one go.

Comment: The whole point of a `recvAll()` function such as you present is to ensure that you receive *all* the data you expect to receive.  `recv()` does not guarantee that you will do.  If the observed behavior changes when you do nothing but switch from `recvAll()` to `recv()`, then it seems likely that the server is still sending exactly the same response, but you're not receiving all of it at once.

Comment: @JohnBollinger:  I'm sorry, but it's still not clear for me.

Comment: @BrianBrown, if the server and its configuration do not change, and the only thing that changes in the client is whether you call `recv()` or `recvAll()`, then it is implausible that the server's response to one version of the client differs from its response to the other version.  Now, study your `recvAll()` function: it's basically just a loop calling `recv()` one or more times.  So, what possibly could be the difference between calling `recv()` *one or more times* and calling it *exactly once*?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Your assumptions are right - it's the only thing I change here. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from your explanation I understood that when I cal `recv` many times in `recvAll` then the client wants to receive the data, but the server has no data to send (because it sent the data for the first `recv` call, and doon't have any more data to handle second and next `recv`'s from client?

Comment: @BrianBrown, the point is that you *need* to be prepared to call `recv()` multiple times, as your `recvAll()` does, to receive the server's complete response.  No single `recv()` call is guaranteed to do that if the response is longer than one byte, no matter what buffer length you specify among the arguments.  If you call `recv()` only once then you may -- and I infer that in this case you ***do*** -- get only partial data.